# How to strike-through text in dot language (graphviz)

Tags: graphviz, dot

I am trying to find out how can I [strike-through](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strikethrough) some text in my nodes in dot based [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) diagrams?

I checked out on this page, but couldn't figure out:
http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html

Googling around didn't help as well.

Consider this diagram, these are basically bug numbers from a bugzilla. The red nodes represent closed bugs, but I do not want to color code them like this. Obviously striken-through <strike>511272</strike> is more intuitive than a red colored node 511272.

[image]

If anyone knows how to strike-through text inside nodes, please share.
thanks,

Shobhit

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Graphviz does not have a styling of its own to do this, but since it is Unicode you can use the technique with [combining characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character#Unicode_ranges) and ["combining long stroke overlay" (U+0336)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/336/index.htm) that the wikipedia article on [strikethrough](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strikethrough) suggests:

> In plain text scenarios where markup cannot be used, Unicode offers a number of combining characters that achieve similar effects.
>   The "long stroke overlay" (U+0336) results in an unbroken stroke
>   across the text,
>
> - Separate: `A̶B̶C̶D̶E̶F̶G̶H̶I̶`
> - Combined: A̶B̶C̶D̶E̶F̶G̶H̶I̶

This graph:

```
digraph G {
    a [label="1̶2̶3̶4̶5̶"]
    b [label="54321"]
    a->b
}
```

Renders this png output with graphviz 2.23.6:

[image: graphviz example with unicode strikethrough]

Comment: Oh man, the answer was right there in front of me, but I didn't see it. You are awesome! Thanks, this solved my problem I have been stuck with since last week. Accepting your answer.

Comment: Here is a good web app for generating these strikethrough characters with three different formats: https://yaytext.com/strike/

Answer (score 4):

Aother option is to use [HTML-like labels](https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#html):

```
digraph G {
    a [label=<<s>12345</s>>]
    b [label="54321"]
    a->b
}
```

[image]